# polygon to point data along with the coordinate

Tags: python, r, gis, arcgis

how to convert polygonal shapefile(.shp) to pointdata(.shp) with latitude and longitude attribute, I just need the coordinate of polygonal boudaries, with in the GIS environment.

Comment: It is related to programming and mean while we can use some gis tools.

Comment: @Username Spatial data analysis etc. is entirely related to programming. There are many things R can do in this area

Comment: This may be what you want to do?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777129/convert-a-shapefile-from-polygons-to-points

Comment: It is useful, but it is not giving as much as accurate for a small village of 4sqkm.